# Get all coincidences to use as criteria on SUMIF

Tags: microsoft-excel

```
-> PAYMENT METHODS TABLE   
NAME SCORE
A    4
B    5
C    6

-> BOOKINGS TABLE
ID DATE   CLIENT   PAYED WITH   PRICE
1  10APR  JOHN     A            500
2  10JUN  PATRICK  B            1000
3  10JUL  JOHN     A            300
4  15JUL  JOHN     C            500
```

I have two tables like these, basically what i need is to be able to match on bookings table by several criteria (date, client, price) and then from all the matches get the 'payment method' name and add up their respective score in 'payment methods table'. Which means i need to get an array of 'payment methods names' (from the matching bookings) and use that as criteria probably within a SUMIF function.

I tried to use this:

```
=SUM(SUMIF(PAYMENT_METHODS_TABLE[NAME],INDEX(BOOKINGS_TABLE[PAYED_WITH],MATCH(1,(BOOKINGS_TABLE[CLIENT]:BOOKINGS_TABLE[CLIENT]="JOHN")*(BOOKINGS_TABLE[DATE]:BOOKINGS_TABLE[DATE]>="10/06/2020"),0)),PAYMENT_METHODS_TABLE[SCORE]))
```

Making it an array formula CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER but it doesnt work, the MATCH function returns only the first 'payment method name' but not all of them

The Formula i want to achieve (Using same criteria than above - ClientName: John and Date greater or equals to "10/06/2020") should look like this:

```
=SUM(SUMIF(PAYMENT_METHODS_TABLE[NAME],{"B","C"},PAYMENT_METHODS_TABLE[SCORE]))
```

Is it possible?

Comment: See edit I added a few other choices, the last includes how to get the array.  as you can see it is very complicated and will be slower than the SUMPRODUCT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use SUMPRODUCT and some Booleans:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((SUMIF(PAYMENT_METHODS_TABLE[NAME],BOOKINGS_TABLE[PAYED WITH],PAYMENT_METHODS_TABLE[SCORE]))*(BOOKINGS_TABLE[CLIENT]="JOHN")*(BOOKINGS_TABLE[DATE]>=DATE(2020,6,10)))
```

[image]

---

IF one has the Dynamic Array Formula `FILTER()`

```
=SUM(SUMIF(PAYMENT_METHODS_TABLE[NAME],FILTER(BOOKINGS_TABLE[PAYED_WITH],(BOOKINGS_TABLE[CLIENT]="JOHN")*(BOOKINGS_TABLE[DATE]>="10/06/2020")),PAYMENT_METHODS_TABLE[SCORE]))
```

[image]

---

to create the list we need to do a complex formula to get the array:

```
INDEX(BOOKINGS_TABLE[PAYED WITH],N(IF({1},MODE.MULT(IF((BOOKINGS_TABLE[CLIENT]="John")*(BOOKINGS_TABLE[DATE]>=DATE(2020,6,10)),(ROW(BOOKINGS_TABLE[ID])-ROW(BOOKINGS_TABLE[[#Headers],[ID]]))*{1,1})))))
```

So:

```
=SUM(SUMIF(PAYMENT_METHODS_TABLE[NAME],INDEX(BOOKINGS_TABLE[PAYED WITH],N(IF({1},MODE.MULT(IF((BOOKINGS_TABLE[CLIENT]="John")*(BOOKINGS_TABLE[DATE]>=DATE(2020,6,10)),(ROW(BOOKINGS_TABLE[ID])-ROW(BOOKINGS_TABLE[[#Headers],[ID]]))*{1,1}))))),PAYMENT_METHODS_TABLE[SCORE]))
```

This is an array formula and depending on one's version it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: Just posted a new question called "Complex Matching and calculating" where i explain with more details what i actually need, if you can take a look that would be amazing!

Comment: BTW just tried this and it worked! Thanks a lot! You're a genius, still need to understand what you did! :)